# Is "port-forwarding" used just for comfort?

Tags: routing, internet, security

If I can easely bind some computer in internal network to a port on the router by code - so its right to say that we need "port-forwording" only for cases that it easier to us then build a new software and bind it to some port?

Comment: Please edit your question and try to add more details

Comment: port-forwarding has nothing to do with port binding. It is related to NAT / PAT.

Comment: Port forwarding is done on configuration screens; not by coding the router itself, usually.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "NO". There is nothing common between "writing software" and port forwarding.
Check here [Why do we need "port forwarding"?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39288/why-do-we-need-port-forwarding) to learn more why port forwarding is needed

Comment: I upvoted you but would suggest that this was more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only good reason for port forwarding is to allow incoming connections to reach a server which is behind the NAT.

For instance, if you are running a normal web server, you will want to use port forwarding (programmed in the router) to allow port 80 to be forwarded into your web server's IP address.

Note that this can open security holes; if your web server gets hacked it will have access to the rest of your network unless you set up a DMZ by using two routers - one with port forwarding into your web server, then another to hide the rest of your network.

Answer (score 0):

For requirement ,  If client wants to access server which is hosted behind firewall  hosted on another networks . Portforwarding is required .

`In firewall`

`Souce : Client IP address`

`Destination as : Server IP address`

`Service port : RDP (TCP-3389)`

`Action : Allow`

`Security profile : ON`